# Using Oracle IMP gives the error IMP-00058

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, imp

I have received some data in Oracle DMP format that I am trying to use imp to import into an Oracle database.

I am running the command:
`imp <user>/<pass>@<tns> FILE=SI_DESIGN_SETS_12Mar2015.dmp`

I get the result:

```
 Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Mar 20 11:59:37 2015

 Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


 IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1031 encountered
 ORA-01031: insufficient privilegesUsername:
```

Running this command with other dmp files has worked in the past. Any ideas on how to get past this error?

Comment: Then the user you are logging in as is missing some privileges.

Comment: I got that, but I can't tell which privileges - as I said, I have been able to import other dmp files. Is there any way to limit IMP to only look at creating tables and data?

Comment: You were successful before connecting as the same user? Is this a full dump (which needs `imp_full_database`) while previous ones were schema/table dumps, perhaps?

Comment: That could be the case, I didn't generate the dmp files. I can see if I can get that permission and try again. Do you know how I would find out if it is a full dump?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that was was prompting for username; so that user can't even connect properly. Can you connect to that user/pass@tns with SQL\*Plus? Are you trying to connect as a privileged user maybe?

Comment: I can connect with my username and password with SQL*Plus and if I add the argument `SHOW=Y` it ends with `import done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SINV's objects into <schema>
Import terminated successfully without warnings.`

Comment: If you aren't connecting as SINV (i.e. `<schema>` is something else) then you're doing at least a fromuser/touser import, I think, so that privilege is still needed. Seeing the full command you're using, and one that's previously worked, might help. I'm rusty on legacy `imp`, life is easier with `impdp` *8-)

Comment: If only I'd received the data with impdp, sadly not an option :( I've asked for imp_full_database, so I will try it with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, I managed to get them to regenerate them and bizarrely adding "FEEDBACK=1000" to the import command actually made some of the old ones work!